# Se desaparece parte de la URL con un Query Vars en WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sql

En mi sitio estoy consultando URL de tipo búsqueda y listando contenidos de un CPT pero se desaparece parte de la URL en el navegador, ejemplo :

Si ingreso al navegador http://sitio.com/?s=wordpress  en el mismo navegador consulta el contenido pero se deshabilita **?s=wordpress** de la URL en el navegador, lo mismo si intento consultar los archivos de un CPT : http://sitio.com/?post_type=custom_post_type se desaparece **?post_type=custom_post_type** , esto puede ser confuso para un usuario.

He deshabilitado todos los plugins, refrescado permalinks y muchas pruebas pero aún no lo logro, también no tiene que ver con mi navegador ya que puedo ver la URL completa de otro sitio por ejemplo : https://ayudawp.com/?s=wordpress .

Instale un plugin llamado Rewrite analyzer para mirar en especifico que pasa con el ?s=wordpress y me arroja lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desactive URL´s amigables - resetee el htaccess (inserte el WP Basic Htaccess)  y nada.

Solo encontré algo muy curioso en la instalación : Le edite en Opciones Generales : Dirección de WordPress (URL) / Dirección del sitio (URL) con la URL finalizada en / pero se refresca siempre y la deja sin / .

Otro dato : La siguiente URL la puedo mirar bien en el navegador : http://sitio.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword no se desaparece ?action=lostpassword .

Comment: Puede que a nivel de WordPress hayas deshabilitado todo, pero has mirado a nivel de Hosting si tienes alguna redirección establecida? Home >> Domains >> Redirects cPanel te da la posibilidad de redirigir al igual que el .htaccess o cualquier plugin.

Comment: A nivel de servidor no es el problema por que tengo 2 hosting , uno para pruebas y otro de producción, me ocurre exactamente lo mismo en los dos ambientes.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64339/discussion-on-question-by-pio-se-desaparece-parte-de-la-url-con-un-query-vars-en).

Comment: El custom type lo programaste vos o era parte del theme / plugin?

Comment: @Juan Hice una prueba de cambiar el Theme y funciona, el theme lo construí a partir de un starter theme llamado underscores y los CPT los cree en forma de plugin.

Comment: Es decir, [que ya detectamos que el problema está en el código del tema](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64338/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-pio). Con cualquier otro tema el problema no se reproduce, funciona como se espera. El principal problema a la hora de resolver esta pregunta es que no tenemos acceso al código fuente del tema para ver qué se está haciendo en él.

Answer (score 1):

Todo apunta a que la redirección a URLs canónicas ([`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) / [`redirect_canonical`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/)) está modificando tu petición GET para hacerla apuntar a la canónica.

Funciona permitiendo que un enlace del tipo `https://pruebas/2017/08/1/hola-mudo/` enlacen a la correcta `https://pruebas/2017/08/1/hola-mundo/` cuando se ha editado el título y el enlace permanente para ser coherente, pero alguien ya ha enlazado al incorrecto.

Viene habilitado por defecto en Wordpress y a veces puede generar ese efecto (aunque yo no he logrado reproducirlo a no ser que desactivara las URLs permanentes).

En versiones anteriores a Wordpress 4.4 se usaba la acción [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), por lo que se usa `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical')` para desactivar la funcionalidad.

A partir de 4.4 se usa un filtro para ello, por lo que hay que usar en su lugar [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical).

En el archivo `functions.php` de tu tema puedes incluir las siguientes líneas:

```
/* A partir de Wordpress 4.4 hay que usar el filtro en vez de la acción */
if (strcmp($wp_version, '4.4') >= 0) {
  remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
} else {
  remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
}
```

Si quieres hacerlo persistente a lo largo de todos los temas puedes crearte un plugin muy básico y guardarlo en `wp-contents/plugins`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Desactivar redirección de URLs canónicas
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       NoMasRedireccionesCanonicas
 * Description:       Desactiva la redirección a URLs canónicas
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Oscar Garcia
 * Author URI:        https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia
 */

/* A partir de Wordpress 4.4 hay que usar el filtro en vez de la acción */
if (strcmp($wp_version, '4.4') >= 0) {
  remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
} else {
  remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
}
```

Hago uso de [`$wp_version`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) para averiguar la versión de Wordpress y usar la solución adecuada, pero si usas una versión actualizada (4.8.1 a día de hoy) basta con que uses únicamente la línea de `remove_filter`.

Yo he creado en mis pruebas el archivo `wp-contents/plugins/nomasredirect/plugin.php` y tras crear el directorio y archivo debes activarlo en el panel de administración de plugins:

[image: activar el plugin]

PD: Acabo de hacer la prueba en un Wordpress que tengo y cualquiera de las dos `remove_filter` o `remove_action` cumplen su misión. ¿Has comprobado el contenido de `functions.php` de tu tema para ver si existe algún `hook` que pudiera estar provocando esa redirección?.

Comment: Elimino mi respuesta hasta que sepa con seguridad si es su tema el que está provocando la redirección.

Answer (score 1):

En lo que hace a rewrite rules, tenés por un lado lo que es externo a wordpress (aunque wordpress también lo manipula) que es lo que tenés definido en el .htaccess.

Por otro lado tenés que Wordpress también maneja internamente rewrite rules.

Cuando creas un CPT se crean reglas automaticamente por ejemplo para que puedas acceder por slug.

Además de las reglas que se crean por default, vos podés agregar reglas adicionales cuando definis el CPT. No se si hiciste eso o no.

Para resolver el problema que tenés es necesario ver la pelicula completa y lleva bastante tiempo, prueba y error.

Lo que te puedo dar son algunas herramientas:

1) Para el .htaccess, podes activar el debug level de como se resuelve el mod_rewrite. [Ver como en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite) Esto se visualiza en el log del web server.

2) Para los rewrite rules de wordpress. Fijate la [api de wp_rewrites](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) como punto de partida. En especial la variable global wp_rewrite tiene todas las reglas que están en curso.

Probablemente tengas que engancharte a un hook cuando parsea el query o cuando lo terminó de parsear.

3) Algo que me es util para debuggiar en wordpress es poner un pequeño plugin casero que escribe al log de wordpress (`../wp-content/debug.log`) y desde el código loguear la salida haciendo `write_log( print_r($variable,true));`

*Nota: Para producción hay que sacar el plugin casero y los write_log() que estén en el código. Y poner todos los define de más abajo en false.*

**wp-config:**

```
...

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

...
```

**plugin:**

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Logger
*/

if ( ! function_exists('write_log')) {
    function write_log ( $log )  {
        if (defined('WP_DEBUG_LOG') && true === WP_DEBUG_LOG){
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
                error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
                error_log( $log );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDICIÓN I**

Estas dos funciones con sus hooks en el functions.php me ayudaron con un proyecto en el que trabajé hace poco.

Podes ver como ser resuleve el query y que regla de rewrite se está aplicando internamente en Wordpress.

```
/******* Para Debugging  **********/

 function print_rewrite_rules($a){
    global $wp_rewrite;

    write_log('wp_rewrite rules:');
    write_log($wp_rewrite);

    write_log('********');
    write_log('Query Vars:');
    write_log($a);

    return $a;
}

add_filter('parse_request', 'print_rewrite_rules', 90, 1);


function print_parsed_request(&$args){
    write_log('Parsed Request:');
    write_log($args);
}

add_action('parse_request','print_parsed_request');
```

Comment: Voy a intentar hacer lo que me comentas, como es algo mas lento te daré mis comentarios de como me va en el paso a paso.

Comment: Agregué un par de funciones que te pueden ayudar a determinar como se está descomponiendo el query y que regla está utilizando para reescribir al url